# Bounding the distance between two points based on their 1st and 2nd derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Is there a known way to place a bound on the distance between two points - here loosley speaking two minima - knowing their first and second derivatives at those specific points?

Say I have two convex functions $G(w)$ and $g(w)$, which are continuous and differentiable at all points.
If
$$w_1 = argmin_wG(w)$$ and 
$$w_2 = argmin_wG(w) + g(w)
$$

can we place a bound on the distance between $w_1$ and $w_2$?